# Como importar CSV no Symfony2

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-2, csv

Estou tentando criar uma forma genérica para importar o CSV o $data representa uma linha completa de dados do csv.

Estou tentando gerar um response para cadastrar os dados usando o form

```
public function save(\Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form, $data ){

    // Campos do formulário
    $fields = $form->all();
    $i = 0;
    $r = new Request();
    $r->setMethod('POST');
    foreach ($fields as $f) {
        $r->request->set($f, $data[$i++]);
    }

    $form->submit($r);
    $form->handleRequest($r);

    if (!$form->isValid()) {
        throw new Exception($form->getErrors());
    }

    $entity = $form->getData();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();
    return true;
}
```

O formulário é sempre inválido, essa é uma função genérica. O objetivo principal dela é ao receber um form gravar os dados, popular a entity relacionada a ele e após, gravar na camada de persistência, como posso fazer isso recebendo como parâmetro o Form?

Comment: Não entendi. Por que você quer fazer isso?

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti Estou fazendo importação de CSV, estou querendo criar algo genérico, o $data na realidade é uma linha do csv. Dessa forma eu posso editar o skeleton do CRUD do Symfony e já ter por padrão a importação do CSV, quero aproveitar a regra padrão de validação e inserção, minha intenção inicial era inclusive passar o Response para o createAction.

Comment: Vou pesquisar uma maneira de fazer isso :)

Answer (score 0):

Bom não sei se valeria a pena testar, mas você já tentou não criar o request, mas sim usar o que é injetado na action?

```
public function saveAction(Request $request)
{
   $form = $this->createForm(new YourForm());
   $form->handleRequest($request);
   // Aqui você chamaria seu método
   $this->save($form, $data);
   //...
}
```

Eu acho que quando você está criando o request na mão, ele perde as referencias e proteções CRFS.

Você poderia testar e ver o que acontece?

Abraços,